# How do I calculate the exponential of a complex matrix?

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm having trouble trying to calculate the exponential of a complex matrix with the C++ Eigen library.

Below is an example code I try to make work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Dense"
#include <complex>
#include "unsupported/Eigen/src/MatrixFunctions/MatrixExponential.h"

int main()
{
    using namespace std::complex_literals;

    Eigen::MatrixXcd test(2,2);
    test(0,0)=1i+std::complex<double>(5);
    test(1,0)=1i*2.;
    test(0,1)=std::complex<double>(2);
    test(1,1)=3.*1i+std::complex<double>(3);

    std::cout << "The matrix exponential is:\n"
              << test.exp() << "\n\n";
}
```

When I run this program I get the error:

```
Implicit instantiation of undefined template 'Eigen::MatrixFunctionReturnValue<Eigen::Matrix<std::__1::complex<double>, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >'
```

I have tried to find an answer but I haven't found one yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

The standard matrix operations in Eigen work and the Eigen file/folder are located in my project folder. The only functions that don't seem to work are the matrix functions in the unsupported folder for complex matrixes (they do work for real ones).

Comment: looks like you are missing some include

Comment: It works for me, simply by replacing `#include "Dense"`by `#include "Eigen/Dense"`

Comment: @Damien I tried it, unfortunately I still get the error

Comment: I am using gcc 8.3.0. How do you compile your program? Is the error rising at compile time or at run time?

Comment: I compile in Xcode with clang as a compiler. The error occurs at compile time. I will try to change to your compiler.

Comment: clang should work, except if it is a very old version. What are you compile/link options?

Comment: I just use the default compile with no options at the moment

Comment: At least the compiler must find where *eigen* is placed. I use the option `-I /home/damien/eigen`

Comment: I tried it, didn't work too. Maybe I should add that the standard matrix operations in Eigen work and the Eigen file/folder are located in my project folder. The only functions that don't seem to work are the matrix functions in the unsupported folder for complex matrixes (they do work for real ones).

Comment: You should have detailed it in the question at the beginning! As it works for me, I will have difficulty to help more.

Comment: Okay I will add it. Thanks for your help anyway:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **must not** directly include headers from the `Eigen/src` or `unsupported/Eigen/src` subdirectories. Also, instead of `#include "Dense"` use `#include <Eigen/Dense>` (in many cases `<Eigen/Core>` is actually sufficient).

In your case you actually just need these includes, because all necessary dependencies are included by `MatrixFunctions`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/MatrixFunctions>
```

Godbolt-Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/PmJWP3 (compilation may occasionally time out).